# Possible download / upload manager embedded on html page with access to local filesystem

Tags: javascript, html, flash, download, filesystems

As the title indicates i want to have a certain application get access to the local file system. To describe why i will illustrate my situation:

I am a running a IIS WebApplication with the C# MVC 4 Framework as backend module. The site solely consists of HTML, CSS markup and some JS. The page will be loaded in IE11+ (Edge) only. For the standard procedure of displaying and accessing data from as well as sending data to the server this works quite fine.

On a certain page I want the user to be able to upload a file using a simple file dialog, like the one you can initiate with a simple `<input type="file">` tag. I also want to offer the posibility to download files from the server but need to know where files has been saved / will be saved to.

As described on a lot of different websites, just like this one here, the HTML5 File API does a great job but will not be able to return the full qualified filename including the local path directions, same for JS accessing the file object.

As my research confirmed HTML5, JS and also SWF (Flash) will not report detailed information because they are all sandboxed applications or restricted by RFCs. I already unterstood and appreciate the effort to secure my trips to internet.

But in this case do need the paths where a file was upload from and the file has been downloaded to.

So my question is, what is the best way to expose the full path directions for a up- as well as downloaded file to report them back to the server?
Is it possible to embed a SWF object inside HTML which will run inside an Adobe AIR sandbox or is a signed JAVA Applet still the one and only solution to accomblish this security breaking task?

A solution i would also apreciate would be the possiblity to ask the user to get access the file system, like you grant access to the web push service to receive notifications.

Also if there is a possible solution which may suite my circumstances please let me know by adding some simeple examples / revealing some factful links, thanks in advance.

Comment: What part of *"can't access local file path"* don't you understand? This is for obvious security reasons....you wouldn't want random sites being able to do that would you?

Comment: As mentioned above i already noticed that and asked for possible ways to embed a "simple" application which may accomblish the task, read the question(s) please.

Comment: There isn't one that will do this in a browser.

Comment: a web page won't ever be able to determine these paths, **but** if you run a local app *(nodeJS or .NET or maybe a browser addon)* to write the files to the FS, they could access/determine these paths. So the webpage would only act as the frontend for this app. I don't know wether this might be a solution for your purpose.

Comment: It would be a solution for me if the solution is simple enough to just access the local recources / application. It would be nice to use common resources like flash or java, which may be installed in most situations, if possible as well. Anyway i have to report the filename (including path) back to the server.

Comment: again, there is no way to do this with anything that is just embedded into a webpage. If it would be so simple to circumvent the sandbox and access the local filesystem, then every f***** google ad could/would do it. On the other hand, if your clients decides to install/run your app on their system, it's their decision.

Comment: `Anyway i have to report the filename (including path) back to the server.` why? It's none of the buisness of any server how I organize my filesystem. If you would explain why this is "necessary", maybe we could find a better solution/approach.

Comment: Please do not comment if you have no intention in answering the question for a solution where limitaions have been marked already, also described as necessary for general purposes. The "why" isn't the real problem here, I am searching to resolve the "issue" and asked for possible solutions around the standard safe way visiting the internet, whereas the user has to permit an application (like flash or java) to perform such an action.